# Is there a way to put a whole Random Forest into one graph instead the single estimators one for one?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, random-forest, graphviz

I tried to visualize the whole RandomForestClassifier rfclf

```
export_graphviz(rfclf, out_file='Graphs/rfclfWhole.dot', 
                feature_names = x.columns,
                class_names = y,
                rounded = True, proportion = False, 
                precision = 2, filled = True)
```

instead to do the following for visualizinig one tree of it as usual:

```
export_graphviz(rfclf.estimators_[5], out_file='Graphs/rfclfWhole.dot', 
                feature_names = x.columns,
                class_names = y,
                rounded = True, proportion = False, 
                precision = 2, filled = True)
```

and got

> NotFittedError: This RandomForestClassifier instance is not fitted
>   yet. Call 'fit' with appropriate arguments before using this method.

But I DO call `rfclf.fit` before

Comment: Just like the error is saying, has the `rfclf.fit` been called?

Comment: yes, .fit has been called @Chris